# 400 BAD_REQUEST "No request body" received when sending a flux of integers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to send a flux of integers from microservice A to B using a POST request. I followed the solution provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75880081/how-to-send-a-flux-of-integers-from-one-microservice-to-another) as a result I was able to hit the endpoint in service B, but getting the following error message:

```
400 BAD_REQUEST No request body for: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<reactor.core.publisher.Mono<java.lang.Void>> com.example.registryservice.controller.RegistryController.createPackage(reactor.core.publisher.Flux<java.lang.Integer>)
```

I tried adding the `@ResponseStatus` attribute to the post endpoint `/packages` in service B as per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661820/spring-reactive-web-applications-post-request-body-is-missing), but still it does not solve the issue.

**Service A:**

```
        Flux<Integer> integerFlux = Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5);
        WebClient.create("http://localhost:9002/registry")
                    .post()
                    .uri("/packages")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON)
                    .body(integerFlux, Integer.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                    .subscribe(System.out::print);
```

**Service B:**

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/packages", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Mono<Void>> createPackage(@RequestBody Flux<Integer> integerFlux) {
        integerFlux.subscribe(new Subscriber<>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                System.out.println("onSubscribe Subscription: " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer t) {
                System.out.println("onNext Integer: " + t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("onError Throwable: " + t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("onComplete");

            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>action</artifactId>
    <name>action</name>
    <description>Action Spring Boot application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me in understanding where am I going wrong?

Comment: BAD_REQUEST generally means your query or your URL is not well formatted, or some parameters are missing. Can you post your full query?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to call the microservice.

Comment: @Sidharth I have provide the code for both the services. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue